# R: selecting elements from data frame

Tags: r

Let's say I want to select the 1st, 3rd, and 12th element from a data frame or a matrix:

```
m = matrix(1:12, 3, 4)
m[c(1,3,12)] # as expected: selects the 1st, 3rd, and 12th element
```

However this does not seems to work for data frames:

```
df = data.frame(m)
df[c(1,3,12)] # doesn't select the elements
```

What I'm using is:

```
as.vector(df)[c(1,3,12)] # works as expected
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?

**EDIT**:

```
as.vector(df)[c(1,3,12)] # does not work
```

As Richard Scriven pointed out:

```
unlist(df, use.names=FALSE)[c(1, 3, 12)] # do work
```

But I'm still looking for a shorter notation (if possible).

Comment: The problem is why would you want to access a data frame using that kind of syntax and on the other hand, isn't the final approach simple enough?

Comment: What's the real use case? It doesn't really sound like rectangular, two-dimensional data.

Comment: check this link http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html about the data structure in R. Matrix and data frame are very different data structures both internally and their usage even though they look similar when printed out.

Comment: Are you sure `as.vector(df)[c(1,3,12)]` works?  I don't think it does. You can use `unlist(df, use.names=FALSE)[c(1, 3, 12)]` to get the same result as with a matrix.  A data frame is a list of vectors.

Comment: @Richard or just `as.matrix`, I guess.

Comment: @mat: `as.vector(df)[c(1,3,12)] # works as expected` does not work

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian you're right it does not work... I wrongly tried as.vector(m)[c(1,3,12)]

Comment: @RichardScriven the unlist version do work, however I'm looking for a shorter notation...

Comment: Okay then `unlist(df, u=FALSE)[c(1, 3, 12)]`.  Notation shouldn't matter as much as doing the job correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  df<-data.frame(11:13,14:16,17:19,20:22)
  df
  #    X11.13 X14.16 X17.19 X20.22
  #  1     11     14     17     20
  #  2     12     15     18     21
  #  3     13     16     19     22


  c(df[df==11], df[df==13],df[df==22])
  # [1] 11 13 22
```

Comment: I think the point of the question is to use indexing, since the actual values may be unknown.

Comment: Ok well we can get indexes if we have a values list. I have been thinking of that too as this is just a small data frame. Still working on it.

Comment: as @RichardScriven said, I'm looking for indexing